# Prevent Function from Being Called Repetitively

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I wrote a custom function to concatenate a range, using a custom concatenator.

```
Public Function mikeConcat(rng As Range, concatenator As Variant) As String
     if left(selection.value,1)="'" then goto end1
     toReturn = "'"
     For Each cel In rng
         toReturn = toReturn & cel & CStr(concatenator)
     Next cel
    mikeConcat = Left(toReturn, Len(toReturn) - 1)
end1: End Function
```

It works great, but it seems the cells in which I use it are constantly calling it. 
Without disabling worksheet formula updating, how do I ensure it's only called once per cell?

Edit1: question to reflect change recommended by FreeMan.
Edit2: I get a circular reference error, and it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe that `Worksheet.Calculate`, whether called in VBA code or by Excel itself will recalculate all cell formulas, including UDFs. That means your function will get called. Period. You could shortcut it by putting a non-printing ASCII character at the end post-conctenation, then check for the existence of that character before you start concatenation.

Comment: But then wouldn't Excel normally be burdened by all formulas in the workbook? 

This is helpful, it would reduce the computation preformed each time calculations are preformed.  Post it as an answer so I can upvote :)

Comment: Please don't edit your original code - it's _very_ confusing to those who come along after you've made the change. If you want to post changed code, do so as a separate code listing

Comment: Yes, Excel is burdened by all the formulas in the workbook - I've got a couple of _very_ formula heavy wkbs that take upwards of a minute to calculate and they don't use UDFs.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your function disable worksheet calculations before it finishes.

Comment: but wouldn't that disable it for my worksheet? I specifically requested an answer that wouldn't interfere with my other formulas.

Comment: @wizlog The idea is that you turn automatic calculations back on when your function is finished. This should not interrupt or interfere with anything else happening on your sheet.

Comment: @wizlog This is the correct answer. `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of your function and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

Comment: I don't think a UDF is (or *should be*) allowed to make such changes to the `Application` state.

Comment: @Mat'sMug what do you suggest?

Comment: @wizlog TBH I think your question is flawed in the first place: a whole entire point of a UDF is that it's invoked whenever Excel needs to recalculate the cell that invokes it. If you want it to be a one-shot deal then write a macro to dump the *result* of that function into each cell that needs it. A UDF recalculates as Excel sees fit, that's what makes it useful.

Comment: @Mat'sMug so instead of returning a string, it should set selection.value = Left(toReturn, Len(toReturn) - 1)?

wouldn't that make it circular?

Comment: No. You make a macro to write the result in the destination cells **instead** of doing `=mikeConcat(A1:A10,",")` in the cells that need the result.